# Why are all NUL removed from my script?

Tags: bash, sh

It seems like bash, and also dash, filter out any ASCII NUL from my scripts.

```
$ printf 'test="\000a" ; echo ${#test}' | sh
1
$ printf 'test="\001a" ; echo ${#test}' | sh
2
$ printf 'ec\000ho test' | sh
test
$ # (Same for bash)
```

While I agree that using NUL is a bad bad idea (for example argument passing to programs works with NUL-terminated strings), I don't see where this behaviour is sanctioned by [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html).

It gets even worse when this behaviour is deciding on the syntactical correctness of the file.

```
$ printf 'echo "\\\000"' | sh
sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
$ printf 'echo "\\\000"' | bash
bash: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
$ printf 'echo "\\\134"' | sh
\
```

What essential part did I miss, or is the NUL-removal only a decision on how to cope with unspecified behaviour?

Comment: All sh implementations I'm familiar with use C strings, which -- being NUL-terminated -- are by their nature incapable of holding NUL values.

Comment: zsh handles all these test cases nicely.

Comment: I'd also try asking Unix & Linux, if @CharlesDuffy's answer does not suffice.

Comment: I was looking through the POSIX specification and surprisingly, I don't see anything prohibiting the use of `NUL`.

Comment: @AlanCurry: Try `printf 'test="\000"; printf "$test" | wc -c' | zsh` and then `printf 'test="\000"; /usr/bin/printf "$test" | wc -c' | zsh`. Not so nice :-)

Comment: I see. It's `printf` that generates the NUL characters. I misinterpreted my results.

Comment: The ksh93 source appears to use null terminated strings throughout.  With Ansi string notation, you can insert a NUL character ($'\0'), but that will immediately truncate the string in further processing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: But it's still surprising that the NUL is stripped out, rather than causing the string to be truncated. (Contrast `$'echo\0foo' bar`, which -- naturally -- prints `bar`, because the `\0` truncates the `$'echo\0foo'` to just `echo`.)

Comment: @JoSo obviously as soon as you pass the string to a non-builtin it has to go through execve() which forces the NULs to be terminators. zsh preserves them as far as it can, unlike the other shells which lose them unnecessarily.

Comment: @AlanCurry: Yes, and that's the point. I am of the opinion that built-ins should adhere to the same semantics as non-builtins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The INPUT FILES section in the standard for [sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) states:

**The input file shall be a text file, except that line lengths shall be unlimited. If the input file is empty or consists solely of blank lines or comments, or both, sh shall exit with a zero exit status.**

The term "text file" is defined in section 3.395  [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_395)  as:

**A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines. The lines do not contain NUL characters and none can exceed {LINE_MAX} bytes in length, including the <newline> character. Although POSIX.1-2008 does not distinguish between text files and binary files (see the ISO C standard), many utilities only produce predictable or meaningful output when operating on text files. The standard utilities that have such restrictions always specify "text files" in their STDIN or INPUT FILES sections**

If the input is not a text file (which it is not if it contains zero bytes), the behavior is neither meaningful nor predictable.

Comment: +1 Seems like what I was looking for. That means, implementations would be best advised to abort on NULs I think.