# How to write an array ignoring space characters in shell scripting?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have a text file which consists of say ..following information say `test.text`:

```
an
apple of 
one's eye
```

I want to read these lines in an array using shell scripting by doing a cat test.text. I have tried using `` a=(`cat test.text`) ``, but that doesn't work as it considers space as a delimiter. I need the values as `a[0]=an` , `a[1]=apple of` , `a[2]=one's eye`. I don't want to use `IFS`. Need help, thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` 4 or later

```
readarray a < test.text
```

This will include an empty element for each blank line, so you might want to remove the empty lines from the input file first.

In earlier versions, you'll need to build the array manually.

```
a=()
while read; do a+=("$REPLY"); done < test.text
```

Answer (score 1):

One of various options you have is to use `read` with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). Set `IFS` to the newline and line separator to NUL

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d $'\0' -a a < test.txt
```

Comment: `$'\0'` is effectively equivalent to `''` (variables are C strings internally)

Comment: @JoSo, good point. I tend to use `$'\0'` for consistency with `$'\n'`

Comment: You're right, that's at least visually more consistent. The downside is that it hides the fact that the shell can't store NULs in variables. The read-NUL-delimited feature in bash is maybe not even intentional but stemming from the fact that the algorithm is "The first character of delim is  used  to  terminate  the input line, rather than newline.", and what happens if the argument is the empty string is not further specified. The implementation simply dereferences the C string corresponding to the variable, yielding the NUL terminator in case of an empty string.

Comment: (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855406/why-are-all-nul-removed-from-my-script )

Answer (score 1):

Plain `sh`

```
IFS='
'
set -- $(< test.txt)
unset IFS
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$@"
```

`bash`

```
IFS=$'\n' a=($(< test.txt))
echo "${a[0]}"
echo "${a[1]}"
echo "${a[@]}"
```

I'm inclined to say these are the best of the available solutions because they do not involve looping.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

```
cat file
an

apple of

one's eye
```

Use this while loop:

```
arr=()
while read -r l; do
    [[ -n "$l" ]] && arr+=("$l")
done < file
```

**TEST**

```
set | grep arr
arr=([0]="an" [1]="apple of" [2]="one's eye")
```